# Possible to take Selenium screenshot when page not fully loaded?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If I stop loading the page after 2 seconds, and it is not fully loaded yet (expected), I still want to take a screenshot of the not-fully-loaded-yet page:

```
seconds = 2
try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(seconds)
    driver.get("http://www.nytimes.com/")
except Exception:
    pass
driver.save_screenshot("nyt_screenshot.png")
```

But it seems as though the save_screenshot() function just loads the page again, either fully or until timeout exception occurs (in which case, the screenshot is not recorded). I can increase that timeout to make sure I get the screenshot, but then I don't get to see what the screenshot looks like at 2, 5, 10, etc. seconds of loading.

I happen to be using chromedriver on mac os x, but open to any driver.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that calling `save_screenshot` method forces the loading of the HTML DOM again from scratch or just completes the the remaining HTML DOM loading? Thanks

Comment: I actually don't know what it's doing behind the scenes, but based on my testing it seems to be reloading the entire HTML DOM again from scratch.